# Why is this find_all method not working rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method that is suppose to iterate over an array and match any items to a string I have in my model. My method looks like this

```
@new_array = @old_array.find_all { |t| t.fetch('name') == "self.object_name" }
```

This method should look thru the array of hashes I have and match any items that have the same name as object_name. When I test the name comparison to the object_name in console it shows true but when I run the full method described above it shows no objects found, however I know the array contains multiple objects with the EXACT same name. Any idea of whats wrong?

The array looks like so...

```
old_array = {"id"=>"123", "account"=>"456", "name"=>"CITY"},
    {"id"=>"456", "account"=>"567", "name"=>"CITY DIR DEP"},
    {"id"=>"456", "account"=>"567", "name"=>"BUCK"},
    {"id"=>"456", "account"=>"567", "name"=>"CITY DIR DEP"},
    {"id"=>"456", "account"=>"567", "name"=>"HAPPY"},
    {"id"=>"456", "account"=>"567", "name"=>"CIRCLE"}
```

and the object prints out in console as

```
self.object_name => "CITY DIR DEP"
```

Comment: This is looking for the hash with a `name` of `self.object_name` literally, so if you had a hash `{"id" => '123', ..., "name" => "self.object_name"}`, it will get returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need quotes `"` at all (you literally trying to compare retrieved `name` with string `"self.object_name"` instead of the value of `self.object_name`):

```
@new_array = @old_array.find_all { |t| t.fetch('name') == self.object_name }
```

If you are a big fan, you can interpolate with `"#{}"`:

```
@new_array = @old_array.find_all { |t| t.fetch('name') == "#{self.object_name}" }
```

Comment: Within the context of `{}`, doesn't Ruby now refer to `self` as `t`? I think OP is using `self.object_name` from an external context as well.

Comment: @sjagr: I guess we are not on the same page. Can you elaborate?

Comment: That got it! but the real problem turned out to be that I had the method as a private method and was calling it in another model. Thanks though for the thorough answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@new_array = @old_array.find_all { |t| t['name'] == self.object_name }
```